# Creating a Laravel project doesn't create the vendor folder

Tags: laravel, composer-php

When I create a project using

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel blog "5.3.*"
```

It creates the project folder but not the vendor folder. I have also tried to use `composer install`, but the vendor folder is still not created.

How would I make it automatically create the vendor folder?

Comment: where did u check for the vendor folder ?
share the directory structure

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel=5.3 blog
```

Because to use specific different version of a package, you place the the desired version after the package name. Also if it doesn't work, try running `composer update`